# Errors installing OMake on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: macos, prolog, makefile, omake, lambda-prolog

I'm trying to install OMake so I can install Teyjus so I can start writing a bit of Lambda Prolog but I'm getting I'm getting a bunch of errors on OS X 10.10.5. The most current one, that I can't figure out, is:

```
*** omake: 497/1193 targets are up to date                                     
*** omake: failed (5.99 sec, 124/124 scans, 81/94 rules, 258/1153 digests)
*** omake: targets were not rebuilt because of errors:                         
   src/libmojave/lm_printf.cmx
   src/libmojave/lm_printf.o
```

Has anyone run into this? Does anyone know of a fix? Would love to be able to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by your posts (here and on [/r/prolog](https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/46urv9/errors_installing_omake_for_teyjus_for_lambda/)) I decided to try and build Teyjus as well, and installed OCaml and OMake along the way. The following describes the steps I took to successfully install OCaml and OMake:

### Installing OCaml

OCaml.org said [the best way to install OCaml was to go through OPAM](https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html). However,
since I chose to install OPAM with homebrew, and OCaml was a prereq, I ended up
with the latest version of OCaml set up after the first two of the following steps:

#### Install opam via homebrew:

Following instructions from https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html

```
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade
$ brew install opam
```

#### Initialize opam

Following the instructions provided by the homebrew results, I ran

```
$ opam init                     # then `y` to allow alterations to the shell profile and another init file
$ eval `opam config env`
```

#### Installing standard libraries

If I'm going to have OCaml installed any how, I might as well get it set up
for proper use, cause eventually I'll want to play around with OCaml itself
again too. Thus, I took the advice of the OCaml installation instructions and
ran

```
$ opam install batteries core
```

### Installing OMake

The [OMake download page](http://omake.metaprl.org/download.html) scared me. I thought, "hey, I've just installed
the robust OCaml package manager, OPAM, and OMake is written in OCaml – so maybe
I can find an OMake package on OPAM and dodge all those deadly bullet-points".
Thus I ran

```
$ opam show omake
```

And saw that omake 0.9.8.6-0 was on offer, which appears to be the most recent
one. So I installed it

```
$ opam update                     # just to be sure ;) But all was up to date
$ opam install omake
```

That should be it! I was able to build Teyjus from source subsequently (I'll post the whole record of my steps on the reddit thread).

---

As an FYI, adding information that answers a question you didn't ask, it looks like Teyjus binaries are also available for OSX: https://github.com/teyjus/teyjus/releases